# How to configure a http integration instead lf a lambda integration using serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda, serverless

**Generalities**

I am working in a Lambda authenticator. I have several modules and require a unique authenticator. This means that a client sends a user and password and a custom authenticator returns a JWT. Then another endpoint is called, the JWT is validated and the request forwarded to the final endpoint.

**Whats working**
The JWT generation is ok and I have a custom authenticator working on lambda which validates the JWT.

**The problem**
I am using serverless framework, and I cant find how to implement a http integration. If I use the console I just select my custom authenticator and pick http from the integration [image: selecting http integration from console] and I am done. The request is received, validated using the custom authenticator and forwarded to an external endpoint.

How can I do this in serverless? I have this config.

```
functions:
hello:
   handler: handler.hello
   events:
     - http:
         path: hello
         method: get
         authorizer: authorize
```

It obviously do not do what I expect. A lambda handler.hello is called after the custom authenticator is done. I dont want to call the external endpoint inside the lambda since it will cost every time. I just want to use an http integration as the one in the console to call another endpoint. Is this possible?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want to create an API gateway with a Lambda Custom Authorizer with an external HTTP endpoint? e.g. if authorized, call gets forwarded to www.test.com

Comment: @K Mo precisely. I want to use api gateway to secure the public api. If authenticated the call is forwarded to another endpoint, i.e. a private api

Answer (score 0):

To create an API Gateway proxy to an external http endpoint with authorization in Serverless Framework, you need to define an api, authorizer and resource method.

This actually breaks down to several CloudFormation actions, but you don't need to worry about that. But be aware that if your deployment fails, a partial stack may still exist.

This example assumes you have already deployed your lambda authorizer. I'm sure there is a way of creating it and referencing the ARN in the same serverless.yml though. I've also added a resource, so to call this service you would call GET {api-url}/{stage}/test.

Example:

```
service: service-name
provider: aws

resources:
  Resources:
    ApiGatewayRestApi:           # create api gateway
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
      Properties:
        Name: TestAuthorizer
    ApiGatewayAuthorizer:           # assign lambda to authorizer
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
      Properties:  
        IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
        RestApiId: 
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        Type: TOKEN
        Name: customAuthorizer
        AuthorizerUri:
          Fn::Join: 
            - ""
            - - "arn:aws:apigateway"
              - ":us-east-1"          # or wherever you are 
              - ":lambda:path/"
              - "2015-03-31/functions/"
              - "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:111111111111:function:myAuthorizerlambda"     # arn of lambda
              - "/invocations"
    ExternalResource:           # create resource on API
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
      Properties:
        ParentId:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - ApiGatewayRestApi # our default Rest API logical ID
            - RootResourceId
        PathPart: test           # the endpoint in your API that is set as proxy
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
    ProxyMethod:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
      Properties:
        ResourceId:
          Ref: ExternalResource
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        HttpMethod: GET           # or what ever the method of your proxy is
        MethodResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
        Integration:
          IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
          Type: HTTP
          Uri: http://test.com           # the URL you want to set a proxy to
          IntegrationResponses:
            - StatusCode: 200
        AuthorizationType: Custom
        AuthorizerId: 
          Ref: ApiGatewayAuthorizer
```